# Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function from getAccounts() + web3 1.0.0-beta.37 + truffle + React Dapp

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask, dapp-development, ganache-cli

I am creating my first Dapp by using web3 1.0.0-beta.37 and trufflfe

While getting the accounts in app.js by using ganache-CLI and Metamask, I am getting  following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function in the console
```

Following is my code of App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import FormSubmitContract from './contracts/FormSubmit.json';
import getWeb3 from './utils/getWeb3.js';



class App extends Component {
  state = {
  web3:null,
  address:null,
};

 componentDidMount = async () =>{
 try{
    const web3 = await getWeb3();
    console.log(web3);
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log(accounts);
    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    const deployedNetwork = FormSubmitContract.networks[networkId];
    const  instance = new web3.eth.contract(FormSubmitContract.abi, 
    deployedNetwork, deployedNetwork.address);
 }catch(error){
  console.log(error);
 }
}
```

I am able to print the web3 in console log

```
Proxy {_requestManager: s, currentProvider: MetamaskInpageProvider, eth: r, db: e.exports, shh: a, …}
```

But got undefined in

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
console.log(accounts); ==> undefined
```

I think there has been change in web3 1+ versions for getting the accounts.

Help me. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Metamask, go to Setting -> Privacy & Security -> deactive the "Privacy Mode" option.

If you want to use the Privacy Mode then you have to modify your code

https://medium.com/metamask/eip-1102-preparing-your-dapp-5027b2c9ed76

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to experiment with:

1. Try using web3 1.0.0-beta.35
2. Are you calling window.ethereum.enable() to unlock the selected user account?

```
   const { ethereum } = window
   if (ethereum) {
      try {
        const web3 = new Web3(ethereum)
        const selectedAccount = await ethereum.enable()
        if (!selectedAccount) {
          // User didn't give permission for dapp to access wallet
          console.log('User opted out')
        } else {
          // User allowed access
          console.log('user gave access!')
        }
        return web3
      } catch (error) {
        // whoopsie!
        console.log(error)
      }
```

Comment: What is it is not the ethereum and  it's web3?

     
      if (window.web3) {       

 

        const web3 = window.web3;       

        console.log("Injected web3 detected.");      

        resolve(web3);      

      }

Comment: For security reasons, the community is encouraged to follow EIP-1102. Please refer to this article: https://medium.com/metamask/eip-1102-preparing-your-dapp-5027b2c9ed76